# Exporting added Calendars and Calendar Groups in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Is there a way to Export or otherwise transfer the lists and folders of other calendars added in Outlook's Calendar view? I use this extensively to view colleagues' calendars and was very unpleasantly surprised to find that they were all removed after a support agent ran the "/resetnavpane" switch. Calendar groups as well as all added calendars disappear when using that command.

For those unfamiliar, I'm referring to calendars added via the "Add Calendar" option and groups created with the "New Calendar Group" as shown here:

[image: screenshot]

**Is there a way to export or transfer added Calendar (Groups)** to a new profile or computer the way I can with Rules or with Ribbon and Toolbar customizations?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the folder structure in your Outlook calendar, I'm afraid that we could not make it with Outlook features alone. Maybe you need to manually add it or you could try some other add-ins.